# Laravel 4.2 include provider before composer update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have a custom Laravel module I wrote that i'm including it in my app.php like so:

```
    'providers' => array(
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
        'My\Custom\Provider'
    );
```

Everytime I run a composer update its stalls saying that my class in unavailable:

```
Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class My\Custom\Provider  not found in ProviderRepository.php on line 157
```

There must be a way to have my provider in the app config, and still be able to run composer update, otherwise its really difficult to auto-deploy my code?

**edit**
What I find myself doing now is commenting the provider from app.php, running composer update, then re-enabling the provider and everything runs fine.

**edit**
Here is my bootstrap/start.php environments

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    // Dev environments
    'dev' => array('dev.xxx.com'),

    // Live server catch
    'live'  => array('live.xxx.com'),

    // EU Server catch
    'eu.west.1.live' => array('eu-west-1.xxx.com'),

    // US server catch
    'us.west.1.live' => array('us-west-1.xxx.com'),

    // Local test environments
    'chris' => array('outrunthewolf-MacBook-Air', 'e7180623aa2e', 'precise64'),

    // Local catch
    'dev' => array('*')
));
```

And my autoload from composer

```
    "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "": "app/controllers/",
        "": "app/libraries/",
        "Model\\": "app/models/"
    }
},
```

Comment: Are you absolutely 100% sure you don't have a typo in the provider name and that the namespace is correct (maybe even a missing CamelCase-uppercase letter)?

Comment: Yes. Just double checked.

Comment: Ok, do you have multiple environments set up? Make sure that your provider is present in all of them. I remember a weird little bug in L4.2 where my environment specific files were not merged correctly with the master file (only concerning nested arrays like the providers), so I copy-pasted *all* providers and facades to each environment specific file. I don't know if the problem still exists, but maybe you could give it a shot.

Comment: And if it's a dev-dependency and you don't want it in your production environment, try running `composer install --no-dev --no-scripts` and 
`php artisan optimize --env="production"` and `php artisan migrate --force --env="production"` on your production end.

Comment: Added the provider to all the app configs, but that didn't solve anything. I do want it in my production environment though.

Comment: Ok, also make sure to always run `php artisan clear-compiled` and `composer dump-auto`. I think this pretty much sounds like the wrong environment is loaded while running the post-update scripts. Make sure you have your environments set up by hostname and that the hostname is correct. Just to make it clear: This is not normal or intended Laravel behaviour, there is clearly a bug somewhere.

Comment: Yeah. Something is wrong somewhere. Perhaps an issue with the package?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think that the package itself should be the issue. The only part of it that Laravel is interested in is the service provider. Maybe it's in a namespace that isn't autloaded? For me it still looks like an environment issue. Could you maybe post the autoload parts from your composer.json and the environments part from your bootstrap/start.php?

Comment: Definately, please see edits

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest some ways to solve this.
1. Please make sure there is no typo in the provider name and that the namespace is correct as suggested by "Quasdunk" in comments.
2. If composer is install on your machine then please execute below command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

It will auto load your all classes. May be it will helps you.

Comment: Yeah I usually run that after I've done a composer update. But I can't complete the composer update to begin with.